# Get locale from language display name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, locale, text-to-speech

I am trying to set my Text-To-Speech language from its display name. The problem is that Text-to-Speech requires a Locale for setLanguage.How do I progress from display language to locale? I first set up my recycler list in this way:

```
 public void getSystemLanguages() {
    systemLanguages = Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
    for (int i = 1; i < systemLanguages.length; i++) {
        String sL = systemLanguages[i];
        Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag(sL);
        String locDisplayResults = loc.getDisplayName();
        languagesList.add(new Languages(locDisplayResults));
        Collections.sort(languagesList, new Comparator<Languages>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Languages languages1, Languages languages2) {
                return languages1.getLocaleDisplay().compareTo(languages2.getLocaleDisplay());
            }
        });
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I then have a recycler adapter which looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                                            final Languages currentLanguages = languagesList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                                            Snackbar snackbar;
                                            snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, currentLanguages.getLocaleDisplay() + " selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                                    .setAction("Next", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                                            chosenLanguage = localeDisplay.getText().toString();
                                                            intent.putExtra("language_key", chosenLanguage);
                                                            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                            View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                                            snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(grey_blue);
                                            snackbar.show();
                                        }
```

I think it should be fairly easy to achieve although I have spent over a week on this with no success. Any help would be fantastic!

Edit: I'm adding my Language class in case anyone can help me with Andreas' solution:

```
    public class Language {

public String localeDisplay;

public Language (String localeDisplay) {
    this.localeDisplay = localeDisplay;
}

public String getLocaleDisplay() {
    return localeDisplay;
```

}
 }
Cheers!

Here is what I've tried:

```
public class Language {

public String localeDisplay;
public Locale mLocale;


public Language(String localeDisplay) {
    this.localeDisplay = localeDisplay;
}

public Language(Locale mLocale){
    this.mLocale = mLocale;
}

public String getLocaleDisplay() {
    return localeDisplay;
}

public void setmLocale(Locale mLocale) {
    this.mLocale = mLocale;
}

public Locale getmLocale() {
    return mLocale;
}
```

}

New edit: here is the correct version:

```
public class Language implements Comparable <Language> {

public String localeDisplay;
public Locale mLocale;

public Language(Locale mLocale, String localeDisplay) {
    if (mLocale != null)
        this.mLocale = mLocale;
    if (localeDisplay != null)
        this.localeDisplay = localeDisplay;
}

public Locale getmLocale(){
    return mLocale;
}

public String getLocaleDisplay(){
    return localeDisplay;
}

public int compareTo(Language l){
    return localeDisplay.compareTo(l.localeDisplay);
}
```

}

Comment: *"How do I progress from display language to locale?"* You don't. You progress from Language Tag to Locale, by remembering the Language Tag that goes with the Display Name, i.e. update your `Languages` class *(should be named `Language`, singular)*, to have both, or even better to have the `Locale` itself.

Comment: Thanks, I can't upvote your answer but I'll try that.

Comment: @Andreas, if at all possible, can you show me how to do it? I have edited my post with what I tried.

Comment: Well, don't create two constructors. Just create one that takes the two parameters and assigns them to fields. Or just take the `Locale` parameter, and let the constructor call `getDisplayName()`. Also, make `Language` implement `Comparable<Language>` and it's `compareTo()` method, so you don't have to create a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Broadcast Receiver listening to locale changes.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

This broadcast receiver would be populating a variable that would be used for populating this adapter.

Note that you will need to notifyDatasetChanged() after new locale changed.

Good luck and i hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, will look into your idea! :)